# How does pointers of array work in the question?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is an question on my textbook.

```
char array[26];
char *cptr = array;
char c;
for(c = 'A'; c<('A'+26);c++)
{
    *cptr ++=c ;
    printf("%d %c %d\n",cptr,c,c);
}
```

I want to know why the variety cptr in this line `printf("%d %c %d\n",cptr,c,c);` could print like

```
6487537 A 65
6487538 B 66
6487539 C 67
6487540 D 68
6487541 E 69
6487542 F 70
6487543 G 71
6487544 H 72
6487545 I 73
```

and not like constant

```
6487536 A 65
6487536 B 66
6487536 C 67
6487536 D 68
6487536 E 69
6487536 F 70
6487536 G 71
6487536 H 72
6487536 I 73
```

Comment: Try to print array to understand what the code is doing `printf("%s", array);` `cptr++` move the pointer

Comment: First of all, printing pointers with `%d` is undefined behaviour. Use `%p` and cast the argument to `(void *)`

Comment: That said, don't write code like `*cptr ++=c ;`, you wont have many friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> char *cptr = array;
> ```

initialize *cptr* to point to the first entry of *array*

> ```
>  *cptr ++=c ;
> ```

is equivalent of

```
*cptr=c;
cptr += 1; /* or "cptr++;" or "++cptr;" as you prefer */
```

so set the element pointed by *cptr* to the value of *c*, then modify *cptr* to point to the next element

so populate *array* with A then B etc

> ```
> printf("%d %c %d\n",cptr,c,c);
> ```

prints (wrongly because the right format is `%p`) the *cptr* then *c* as a character then the character code, so print the address of each element of the array + 1

You will have the same prints doing :

```
printf("%d %c %d\n",cptr,cptr[-1], cptr[-1]);
```

even again to print the address the right format is not `%d` but `%p`, so

```
printf("%p %c %d\n",cptr,cptr[-1], cptr[-1]);
```

Comment: so you didnt need to to something like ```i++; (cptr+i)```?

Comment: @DanielYen no because of the `++` in `*cptr ++=c ;` (better written `*cptr++ = c;` ) doing `cptr += 1;` (or `cptr++;` or `++cptr;` as you prefer)  as I say in my answer. DO you understand ?

Comment: so ```cptr += 1``` make the ```cptr```in ```printf("%d %c %d\n",cptr,c,c);``` "move"?

Comment: @DanielYen yes, before to enter in the loop *cptr* values `&array[0]`, then the code assign that entry and increment *cptr* to be `&array[1];` then ..., so the *printf* write `&array[1];` then `&array[2];` ... then `&array[26];` because the print address is *after* the incrementation

Comment: Thank you. It bother me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The spaces in `*cptr ++=c ;` may be misleading. Better spacing would be `*cptr++ = c;`. The precedence of the operators causes this to be grouped as `*(cptr++) = c;`. This means:

- `cptr++` says to increment `cptr` by 1. However, the value used in this expression will be the value before the increment.
- `*cptr++` says to use the pointed-to location. This will be the location where `cptr` pointed to before the increment.
- `*cptr++ = c;` puts the value of `c` in the pointed-to location.

Also note you should not print a pointer with `%d`. To print a pointer, convert it to `void *` and print using `%p`: `printf("%p %c %d\n", (void *) cptr, c, c);`.